# One little step from success...javascript alt

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, alt

I want my Facebook sharer in Fancybox to catch alt of an image and place it as Title of link.

With this code below, I'm getting "undefined" title, and the rest is fine.

What's wrong with it?

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow : function() {
        var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');

        this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);

        this.title = alt;
    }
});

$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            if (this.title) {
                // New line
                this.title += '<br />';

                // Add tweet button
                this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

                // Add FaceBook like button
                this.title += '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=' + this.href + '&p[title]=' + this.alt + '&p[images][0]=' + this.href + '&p[summary]=My website summary">Facebook</a> ;'
            }
        },
        afterShow: function() {
            // Render tweet button
            twttr.widgets.load();
        },
        helpers : {
            title : {
                type: 'inside'
            }
        }  
    });
```

This is the code for images:

```
<a class="fancybox" title="Title displayed under image" alt="alttext" href="Link to big image" rel="group"><img alt="alttext" src="Thumb" /></a>


<div class="hidden">
<a class="fancybox" title="Title displayed under image" alt="alttext" href="Link to big image" rel="group"><img alt="alttext" src="Thumb" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" title="Title displayed under image" alt="alttext" href="Link to big image" rel="group"><img alt="alttext" src="Thumb" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" title="Title displayed under image" alt="alttext" href="Link to big image" rel="group"><img alt="alttext" src="Thumb" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" title="Title displayed under image" alt="alttext" href="Link to big image" rel="group"><img alt="alttext" src="Thumb" /></a>
</div>
```

Basically hidden class is used to hide all images except the one on the top, however they are still browsable through Fancybox.

---

ANOTHER EDIT:

I have added div over the first image in order to test it

```
    <div class="fancybox"><a class="fancybox" title="Title displayed under image" alt="alttext" href="Link to big image" rel="group"><img alt="alttext" src="Thumb" /></a></div>
```

What happens - If I will leave the alert, it pops up with proper title.
However, when I click on image, only picture shows up without social buttons.

Comment: If you initialize fancybox twice, only the last will be taken into account so whatever API options you have in your first call will be overridden by the second. And by the way, you just need to set `class="fancybox"` to the anchor tag and not its parent container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alt attribute of an image is not available from inside Fancybox and can't be passed to it either (without adapting fancybox.js). That's why `this.alt` in your second call to `beforeShow()` returns `undefined`.

You would need to use another method to pass the desired string to your Facebook link. If the alt text is the same as the title text, how about doing something like:

```
 if (this.title) {

            // pass original title to new variable
            var originalTitle = this.title;         

            // New line
            this.title += '&lt;br /&gt;';

            // Add tweet button
            this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

            // Add FaceBook like button ## using originalTitle
            this.title += '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=' + this.href + '&p[title]=' + originalTitle + '&p[images][0]=' + this.href + '&p[summary]=My website summary">Facebook</a> ;'
        }
```

The alt attribute is not allowed in anchor tags - is there any reason for it being there?

Comment: Thank you!
This seem to work perfectly, however I still got one problem.

Comment: Do share the problem. I've been through some pain with Fancybox too :)

Comment: Had to quit for a second and couldn't finish editing comment.
How can I make this code to open a default Facebook Sharer popup? At this moment sharer opens in the same window. If I add target _blank it opens the sharer in new tab/window in fullscreen. Both these options are anti-usability. I Have tried with window.open but unsuccessfully.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a fancybox issue - best to open a separate question.

Comment: Thanks. You can check it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538016/facebook-sharer-jquery

Comment: `The alt attribute of an image is not available from inside Fancybox and can't be passed to it either (without adapting fancybox.js` ... not necessarily true. You can always get it from within a callback without editing the fancybox js file at all.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a misuse of the http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/.

If the  tag is a child (nth level) of an element with the .fancybox class, and you are trying to get the 'alt' attribute of that tag, then I would try omitting the element command.

```
var alt = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/benashby/avGk6/

Note: if the img you are after is a 1st level child of the fancybox div, it would be easier on the cliet to use the http://api.jquery.com/children/ command or some derivation of it.

Comment: Thank you. It does work on JSfiddle, I've tried this code on my website, I got the right altert. I deleted alert line - sharer still doesn't get the alt. I edited the main question so you can see more code.