# Facebook Sharer + jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook

I want to be able to use default Facebook Share dialog.

I'm using this code to be able to use Facebook Share button inside my Fancybox gallery:

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.title) {

            // pass original title to new variable
            var originalTitle = this.title;  

            // Add FaceBook like button
            this.title += '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=' + this.href + '&p[title]=' + originalTitle + '&p[images][0]=' + this.href + '&p[summary]=My website summary"><img src="#"></a> ';
        }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        // Render tweet button
        twttr.widgets.load();
    },
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }  
});
```

The thing is that at this moment it tries to share the picture in the same window(tab) instead of a popup. 
Having to "go back" for users may seem very annoying.

This is default code provided by Facebook:

```
<a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

And this is HTML used to display pictures:

```
<a class="fancybox" title="My Image Title" href="#" rel="group"><img src="#" /></a>
```

Also, how to add counter of Shares? Displayed right to the button.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want a new window and don’t care about it’s dimensions, then just add `target="_blank"` to your link. Btw., you should escape the parameter values you put inside the link address with `encodeURIComponent`, otherwise GET parameters in your own URL might get lost.

Comment: _blank is not an option. Using default parameters is what I have to use - only this way when using Fancybox Facebook Sharer can fetch everything correctly.